# How to override LISTAGG function of oracle for H2 database

Tags: java, oracle, h2

I tried to implement it using custom functions, But Within group(order by) syntax give bad SQL grammar

Comment: H2 has [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#group_concat)

Comment: Why are you trying to run Oracle code in an H2 database?